# Got sockect error trying to find packeage test at https//pub.dev

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-pub, flutter-pubspec

```
C:\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
Resolving dependencies in ..\\..\\..\\..\\flutter\\packages\\flutter_tools...
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Got socket error trying to find package test at https://pub.dev.
pub get failed
command: "C:\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin\\dart \__deprecated_pub --directory ..\\..\\..\\..\\flutter\\packages\\flutter_tools get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\\Users\\Anselemcrizy\\AppData\\Local\\Pub\\Cache",
}
exit code: 69
```

I was trying to run flutter pub get

Comment: Please can someone help me with the solution to fix this error

Comment: What is the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: `Flutter device daemon #1 exited (exit code 69), stderr: Got socket error trying to find package test at https://pub.dev.`

Answer (score 0):

If you manually downloaded the flutter zip file and extracted it to the src folder on your C drive rather than cloning the repository with git, simply delete the extracted file and proceed as follows:

1. Launch your terminal
2. Execute "cd.." twice.
3. Then execute cd src
4. Finally, execute "git clone [https://github.com/flutter/flutter"](https://github.com/flutter/flutter%22) to clone the
   repository.

This should clone the Flutter repository in the correct location, and you should be able to run "flutter doctor" command without any issues.

It should look like this:

> C:\Users\Abba>cd ..

> C:\Users>cd ..

> C:>cd src

> C:\src>git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter
> Cloning into 'flutter'...
> remote: Enumerating objects: 443987, done.
> remote: Counting objects: 100% (1813/1813), done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (717/717), done.
> remote: Total 443987 (delta 1109), reused 1467 (delta 930), pack-reused 442174
> Receiving objects: 100% (443987/443987), 249.96 MiB | 4.87 MiB/s, done.
> Resolving deltas: 100% (337808/337808), done.
> Updating files: 100% (7493/7493), done.

Comment: Okay thanks lety me try this

Answer (score 0):

For me, running `flutter clean` solved it. It gives an error as shown but after running `flutter upgrade` it shows that it solved the issue. [image: What you might expect to see and what it gave me]